# Why does false = isinstance(a, Int) when a is a integer

Tags: python

I’m trying to make a online calculator without any errors.

When `a` , `b` and `c` gets a input  it is supposed to calculate the answer and print it

But when a or b is not an integer then it is supposed say “ the first input and the second input needs to be a number”

[a image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtn99.png)

Although a and b were a integer/number it still responded with “the first input and the second input needs to be a number”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use  `isdigit()`  method to check whether it is a number or not

On your code:-

```
a = input()
if a.isdigit():
```

However, if you want to take the user's input as an integer directly and you expect the input to be a number, then it would be more efficient to use the `int()` function. This function will try to convert the input to an integer, and if it is not a number, it will raise a `ValueError` exception which you can catch and handle as appropriate.

```
try:
    a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    print("The number you entered is: ", a)
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid input, please enter a number.")
```